# Get last recorded value from influx if no entries in timespan

Tags: chart.js, influxql

I am recording the value of a sensor to influx every time it changes. The frequency varies wildly. It may be every 30 seconds, or once every 2 weeks. It fluctuates based on environmental conditions. I do not have much control over this process.

I am using the query below to plot it's value in 5 minute increments on a line graph (chart.js) for the current shift. If the value didn't change in that 5 minutes, it just shows the previous value.

```
SELECT last(C104) as LC104 FROM SPC WHERE time>=2023-07-05T07:00:00Z GROUP BY time(5m) fill(previous)
```

This works well, as long as there is at least 1 entry in the database after that timestamp. If there is not, I will get all null values.

How can I also pull in the last recorded value and use that in place of the null values?

Comment: My temporary solution is to have a standalone script that runs at the beginning of each shift, takes the last value (which is easy to get) and inserts it into influx as a new value. Then I have a value at the beginning of a shift to reference.

Looking at this page, it seems to be an ongoing issue with influx that doesn't have an easy/efficient solution.

https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/6878